# How to print a 2d spiral matrix in counter clockwise using php

Tags: php, matrix, 2d, spiral

I am trying to print a spiral matrix in anticlockwise using php but iam not getting any idea or logic about the same.I am trying to print a matrix in below mentioned form:

1    2   3   4   5 
16 17 18 19 6 
15 24 25 20 7 
14 23 22 21 8 
13 12 11 10 9

iam trying following..tell me if iam going wrong

```
$spiral=[
     [1,2,3,4,5],
     [6,7,8,9,10],
     [11,12,13,14,15],
     [16,17,18,19,20],
     [21,22,23,24,25]
    ];




 function spiral_matrix($sp)
 {
 $i='';$j='';$k='';$l='';
  for($i=0;$i<sizeof($sp);$i++)
  {
   for($j=0;$j<sizeof($sp);$j++)
   {
 if($i==0)
 {
   print_r($sp[$i][$j]);  
 }  

 if($i==1)
 {

  echo '<br/>';
  echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';

  print_r($sp[$i][$j]);  
 }


}
echo '<br/>';

 }


}
```

any ideas or suggestions would be great?

Comment: What have you tied so far? Can you post an example of your code? Also see here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i put the code,which iam trying...kindly tell me if iam going in wrong direction

Comment: There is conflict in your expected output.   **anticlockwise** does not equal `1   2   3   4   5
16 17 18 19 6
15 24 25 20 7
14 23 22 21 8
13 12 11 10 9`  ...that is the way all of my clocks go.

Comment: i mean clockwise..